# Verbs with current Subjunctive II Usage

Tags: subjunctive, verb-choice, verb-usage

Okay so in a previous question:

[Difference between "Ich möchte" and "Ich hätte gern(e)" and "Ich würde gern(e)"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22566/difference-between-ich-m%C3%B6chte-and-ich-h%C3%A4tte-gerne-and-ich-w%C3%BCrde-gerne)

A reply to an answer by Jan brought up a great question. "the question is only if it is in current usage or not"

Well, instead of memorizing Subjunctive II forms for verbs that more commonly use "würde" I think a list of the commonly used ones would be of great help to me and others studying such things.

So, to rephrase... Which verbs are commonly used in their Subjunctive II form? Verbs not mentioned will be assumed to use "würde" more commonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most frequently encountered will probably be *möchte* from *mögen*.

Others I can think of:

- hätte
- wäre
- könnte
- dürfte
- müsste
- sollte
- wüsste
- bräuchte

Some are much more common in specific dialects (of course in their dialectal form):

- täte (Bavarian dad)
- ginge (Bavarian gangat)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know so few were used. That's good news for people studying the Subjunctive II though. You're the best!