# Wie werden Präteritum und Konjunktiv II im Alltag unterschieden?

Tags: subjunctive, preterite

Der Konjunktiv II ist das Präteritum mit Umlaut (z.B. esse → aße → äße).

Wenn die Präteritum-Form des Verbes keine Umlaut bekommen kann, passiert dies nicht (z. B. gehe → ginge → ginge).

Das resultiert, daß die Präteritum und die Konjunktiv-II-Formen im Fall der im Präteritum nicht umlautfähigen Verben gleich sind.

Z. B. *ich ginge* kann eine ähnliche Bedeutung wie *ich würde gehen* (wie Konditional im Präsens) aber auch *ich bin gegangen* (nicht Konditional, in der Vergangenheit) haben.

Englisch hat das gleiche Problem: Der entsprechende Modus (past subjunctive) unterscheidet sich nur noch bei einem Verb von der Vergangenheitsform, und das auch nur in der ersten und dritten Person Singular.

Wie wird dieses Problem in der alltaglichen Sprache gelöst?

Comment: Trifft nicht auf alle Formen zu; in der 1. und 3. Person Singular unterscheiden sich die Endungen: _ich ging_, _sie ging_ (Präteritum); _ich ginge_, _sie ginge_ (Konjunktiv). Gravierender ist es bei den schwachen Verben, wo wirklich alle Formen zusammenfallen (_er schaute_).

Comment: Ich habe Deine erste Frage entfernt, da *Weiß ich es gut?* oder *Habe ich recht?* keine guten Fragen für diese Seite sind. Was Du machen kannst, ist eine Frage über das zu stellen, was Du überprüfen möchtest (z. B.: »Wann sind Konjunktiv II und Präteritum identisch?«), und diese dann selbst zu beantworten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich habe mich noch nicht auf die Suche nach Grenzfällen gemacht, aber normalerweise hilft der Rest des Satzes oder zumindest der Kontext, die Zeitform zu bestimmen. Bei Aussagen im Präteritum solltest Du eine Angabe über den Zeitpunkt der Handlung finden - Wörter und Wendungen wie "gestern", "letztes Jahr", "als ich aus dem Urlaub zurückkam". In Konjunktiv-Sätzen findest Du hingegen Wörter, die eine Bedingung anzeigen, z.B. "falls", "wenn", "unter der Bedingung, dass", "angenommen".

Answer (score 1):

Da die ursprünglichen Bedeutungsnuancen der verschiedenen Konjunktive im Deutschen sowieso verloren gegangen sind, gibt es in der alltäglichen Sprache überhaupt kein Problem.

Es gibt eine würde-Umschreibung mit der sich jede Verwechslung mit anderen indikativen Verbformen disambiguieren lässt. Der Konjunktiv wird eigentlich nur mehr in der indirekte Rede und zur Bildung einer Kondition gebraucht. Ebenso wie im Englischen wird er auch noch zum Ausdruck eines Wunsches 'Ich wünsche, du wärst hier' ('Wish you were here') verwendet, aber das ist schon ein Überbleibsel aus alten Zeiten.

Obwohl die Systematik den Konjunktiv in 'Zeiten' einstuft sollte man nicht den Fehler begehen, dieses Zeitengefüge als 'absolut' zu betrachten sondern als 'relativ'. Mit dem verkorkten deutschen Konjunktiv-Salat ist es dtsch. Muttersprachlern nicht mehr möglich, verlässliche Angaben über den Gebrauch zu machen.

- Du sagtest mir gestern, du **wärst** in Berlin!
- Jetzt willst Du mir plötzlich einreden, du **wärst** in Berlin?
- Morgen würdest du mir sicher einreden, du **wärst** in Berlin!

Für diese 'relative' Gefüge gibt es aber in keiner Sprache die ich kenne so klare und eindeutige Termini wie im Deutschen.

***vorzeitig - gleichzeitig - nachzeitig***

Alle modalen Phänomene wie Konjunktiv - Subjuntivo - Imperativ sind hauptsächlich unter diesem Gesichtspunkt zu betrachten auch wenn das System in der eigenen Muttersprache schon verkümmert ist! Aber das ist eine andere Spielwiese... - Wer sich wirklich dafür interessiert, sollte eine romanische Sprache zu Rate ziehen, vorzugsweise Spanisch - auf keinen Fall Französisch!

Comment: Bevor das hier völlig unübersichtlich für Unbeteiligte wird, habe ich mal die Kommentare in den [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27749/discussion-on-answer-by-mramosch-wie-werden-prateritum-und-konjunktiv-ii-im-allt) verschoben.

Answer (score 1):

Prinzipiell sind die Formen des Konjunktivs II zum großen Teil aus dem Alltag verschwunden – siehe [diese Frage (auf Englisch)](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22604).

Sofern sie denn überhaupt noch benutzt werden, tauchen sie eher im Süden denn im Norden auf (und eher bei akademisch gebildeten) – und interessanterweise deckt sich das wunderbar mit dem Gebiet, das im Deutschen auch kein Präteritum kennt (außer bei den Verben *sein* und *wollen*).

Das heißt, das Problem wird rein praktisch gelöst: Dort, wo das Imperfekt noch verwendet wird, wird der Konjunktiv noch viel stärker mit *würde* gebildet. Umgekehrt wird dort, wo nur das Perfekt als Vergangenheitsform verwendet wird, gelegentlich etwas häufiger eine Konjunktivform eingestreut.

Ich habe sogar irgendwo irgendwann mal gelesen, dass das eine mit dem anderen zu tun habe: Weil die Vergangenheit als zusammengesetzte Zeit aufgebaut wurde, hat sich der Konjunktiv im Süden besser halten können. Ob das allerdings eine vertrauenswürde Quelle war, kann ich nicht mehr nachvollziehen.